# Uniqueness of primitives

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

We all know that a primitive $F(x)$ of a function $f(x)$ is the function which derivative is $f(x)$. For example:

$$\int 2x dx = x^2 + C$$

where $x^2 + C$ is the set of all primitives of the function. However, how can I be sure that $x^2 + C$ is the only possible solution? How can I be sure that a function $f(x) \ne x^2 + C\ ,\ f'(x) = 2x$ does not exist?

How could I create a mathematical proof of this fact (in this specific case and in the general case)? Does it make sense to seek such a proof? If not, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you said is a consequence of the following:

If $f^{\prime}=g^{\prime}$ then $f=g+c$ for some constant $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

To prove this let $h=f-g$. Then $h$ is differentiable and $h^{\prime}=f^{\prime}-g^{\prime}=0$. $h$ is therefore constant (*), that is $\exists c\in \mathbb{R}:h(x)=c$. Then, $f(x)=g(x)+c$

Therefore, a continuous function always has a primitive, unique up to additive constant.

(*) This is an important consequence of the Mean Value Theorem.
Here is a proof of that

Let $f$ be continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$ so that $f^{\prime}\equiv 0$. Let $x,y\in [a,b]$ and WLOG $x<y$. By the MVT in $[x,y]$,
\begin{equation}\exists \xi \in (x,y):f^{\prime}(\xi)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\implies\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=0\implies f(y)=f(x)\end{equation}
and so $f$ is constant

Comment: The "$h$ is therefore constant" claim needs proof.

Comment: As I said to Pete, I can't see the answer in your text. I've updated my question to better explain my problem.

Comment: @user16538 What exactly do you not understand in my answer?

Comment: @user16538 he is saying: given two anti-derivatives, $f$ and $g$, they may only differ by a constant.

Comment: Your proof tells me that $C$ must be constant (this is fine), but not that $f$ is unique (and that's my problem).

Comment: @Jonathan: you are right. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Your question is eminently sensible and indeed important.

The keyword here is **Mean Value Theorem**, or more specifically its special case that a function defined and differentiable on an interval with identically zero derivative must be constant.  For more details, see (e.g.) $\S 5.1$ of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf).

Here are some further remarks:

$\bullet$ Of course it is understood here that all functions are defined on an *interval* $I$.  If we look at functions with more complicated -- and in particular disconnected -- domains, then uniqueness of primitives up to a constant need not hold.  One sees the ugly head of this in freshman calculus when students are taught (not by me!) that the antiderivatives of $\frac{1}{x}$ are $\log |x| +C$.

$\bullet$ The fact that a function which is differentiable on an interval with identically zero derivative is constant -- I call this the **Zero Velocity Theorem** -- is actually quite deep.  As mentioned above, it is a consequence of the Mean Value Theorem.  In turn it holds in an ordered field iff the field is Dedekind complete, as is shown in Jim Propp's nice article [Real Analysis in Reverse](http://faculty.uml.edu/jpropp/reverse.pdf).  It is easy to construct counterexamples over $\mathbb{Q}$: just take a piecewise constant function with discontinuities at irrational numbers.

$\bullet$ A proof of the Zero Velocity Theorem directly from an equivalent of the least upper bound axiom -- specifically, using **Real Induction** -- is given [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/instructors_guide_shorter.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not think it addresses my question (or, better, I cannot see _how_). I've updated my question to better explain my problem.

Comment: @user16538: Unless I am very much mistaken, I am answering your question.  I am explaining the proof that if $F$ is one primitive of a function $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then any other primitive $G$ is of the form $F + C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: This real induction is real nice.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(x)$ be a function such that $F'(x)=2x$ for all $x$. Let $G(x)=F(x)-x^2$. Then $G'(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Let $G(0)=C$. By the Mean Value Theorem, for any $x\ne 0$ there is a $t_x$ between $0$ and $x$ such that
$$\frac{G(x)-G(0)}{x-0}=G'(t_x).$$
Since $G'(x)$ is identically $0$, it follows that $G(x)-G(0)=0$, that is, that $G(x)=C$. Thus $F(x)=2x+C$ for all $x$.

**Remark:** Let us find all the antiderivatives of $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$. Here the correct answer is not quite the conventional one. By the argument above, one can show that if $F'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ then there is a constant $C$ such that  for all *positive* $x$, we have $F(x)=-\dfrac{1}{x}+C$.

Similarly, there is a constant $D$ such that   for all *negative* $x$, we have $F(x)=-\dfrac{1}{x}+D$.

But the constants $C$ and $D$ need not be equal. The singularity at $x=0$ prevents the derivative from transferring information from the positives to te negatives.

Comment: Sometimes you can go around the singularity.